# What to do when /etc/network/interfaces is missing on Debian?

Tags: networking, debian

I just configured a Debian 10 virtual private server on a new hosting provider and somehow `/etc/network/interfaces` is missing.

Running `ip a` reveals a `lo` and `eth0@if24` interface.

Trying to add an interface alias to `eth0@if24`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Wesley, I figured it out.

That VPS was configured to use [SystemdNetworkd](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdNetworkd) so files in `/etc/systemd/network` instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Also, thanks to Michael, I learned that interface aliases are a thing of the past.

See [How to configure interface aliases using Systemd-Networkd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1029004/how-to-configure-interface-aliases-using-systemd-networkd).

Answer (score 1):

Your "virtual machine" is actually a container, not a virtual machine, and it appears your container host is configuring networking for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The hosting provider is using LXD vs KVM... do you know how I can add interface aliases in this context?

Comment: @sunknudsen You don't add interface aliases. They have been deprecated for more than a decade. Just add the additional IP addresses to the interface.

Comment: I am actually trying to solve https://serverfault.com/questions/1029000/how-to-fix-no-address-range-available-for-dhcp-request-error hence why I am trying to create the alias. Have a moment to help?

Comment: @sunknudsen Again, you don't add interface aliases. They don't even strictly exist anymore. If you think you are making one, it's ignored and the IP address is added to the specified interface, no alias, just a human readable label attached to the IP address. As for the other problem, this probably isn't the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your host is probably using NetPlan and CloudInit. `/etc/network/interfaces` is old and deprecated, so... don't use it. Check for the existence of `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` [Have a plan for netplan](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/have-plan-netplan)

Comment: Thanks for helping out Wesley. `cat: /etc/netplan/config.yaml: No such file or directory` and `ls: cannot access '/etc/cloud': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Is the yaml file missing, or the directory? There isn't a config.yaml file by default, but the netplan directory exists. Also, there should be a `netplan` command in your path, e.g. `netplan --help`

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/etc/netplan/': No such file or directory` and `-bash: netplan: command not found`

Comment: So it would seem that initial networking is set up by cloudinit, but then netplan is left as an exercise for the customer.

Comment: Are we sure netplan is involved? There has to be a file somewhere to configure this right?

Comment: Btw, do you know what is up with `@if24` in `eth0@if24`?

Comment: Ah, right, I spaced it. This is systemd-networkd in the mix, so yes, netplan is out. systemd is in. You'll probably see some stuff with `systemctl list-units -t network`. Or not - depending. :D

Comment: Running `systemctl list-units -t network` returns `Unknown unit type or load state 'network'.`. This is quite a puzzle!

Comment: Another way around my issue would be solving https://serverfault.com/questions/1029000/how-to-fix-no-address-range-available-for-dhcp-request-error. Do you have a moment to have a look?

Comment: I just hacked out the `-t network` as a semi-educated guess. TL;DR systemd-networkd is likely your next avenue.

Comment: Thanks Wesley! We’re onto something. `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` exists. Now I have to figure out how to add aliases in the context of systemd.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/1029004/how-to-configure-interface-aliases-using-systemd-networkd

Comment: Hey Wesley, thanks to your help I got things sorted. Thanks! It was systemd-networkd. Do you want to update your answer or should I submit one? See https://serverfault.com/questions/1029004/how-to-configure-interface-aliases-using-systemd-networkd.

Comment: @sunknudsen You should probably write your own - you did all the heavy lifting. Reap the benefits! :D

Comment: Couldn’t have done it without you but okidoki.