# How to fix "no address range available for DHCP request" error?

Tags: networking, debian, dnsmasq

Trying to run a DHCP server on `lo` using dnsmasq.

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/01-dhcp-loopback.conf
interface=lo
dhcp-range=10.0.2.10,10.0.2.254,255.255.255.0
port=0
```

I can get things working by adding the following alias to `eth0`, but that doesn’t make sense right?

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.0.2.1/24
```

Comment: What are you trying to give DHCP addresses to?

Comment: @Bert I am trying to use strongSwan’s [DHCP plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/DHCPPlugin) to assign IPv4 addresses to clients.

Comment: You don't want to run DHCP on `lo`, that's your loopback that's only accessible by the server itself. You want to run it on the network, so use an ethernet device like `eth0`

Comment: @Bert If I want the DHCP server to serve IPs to VPN clients only... does your comment still apply? I was told to bind the DHCP server to `lo` to isolate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't configure eth0 as it's a container, not a real VM, and the host controls the network.

In a real VM you could create a dummy interface and use that. Since you have a container, this depends on whether the container host has loaded the dummy module (and the chance is pretty close to 100% that they have not).

```
iface dummy0 inet static
    address 10.10.0.1/24
    pre-up ip link add dummy0 type dummy
```

Comment: Interesting... what is the equivalent for that for systemd?

Comment: @sunknudsen Probably much the same as any other interface, except that networkd expects the interface to already exist, so you'd probably have to write a custom unit to create it before networkd starts.

Comment: Michael, would you set `interface=lo` to `interface=dummy0`?

Comment: @sunknudsen Only if that's what you decide to name it.

Comment: Michael, in your above example, `dummy0` is the name right (didn’t know about dummy interfaces, thanks!)? So it’s normal to bind a dnsmasq DHCP server to a dummy interface right?

Comment: I am having a strange issue now where strongSwan clients are not assigned an IPv4 address from the DHCP pool the first time they connect, but the second time, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no intention to use DHCP on this host, but get this error from Dnsmasq, then you need to disable DHCP, by commenting out all

```
dhcp-*
dhcp-range=
```

lines in both files:

> /etc/dnsmasq.d/dhcp-settings

and

> /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Then just restart the service:
`sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq`