# How to configure interface aliases using Systemd-Networkd?

Tags: networking, debian, systemd, systemd-networkd

I am trying to port the following alias from `/etc/network/interfaces` to `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`.

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.0.2.1/24
```

Comment: You don't. Interface aliases don't exist anymore.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks Michael, so how can I add another IP to `eth0` then? I am trying to solve https://serverfault.com/questions/1029000/how-to-fix-no-address-range-available-for-dhcp-request-error.

Comment: It's a container, not a real VM. You probably don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, you don’t.

Instead, you add additional `Address=` and `Gateway=` lines to the interface.

Example:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2a0a:3840:1337:126::b9c1:7ecb:1337/64
Gateway=2a0a:3840:1337:126::1
IPv6AcceptRA=no

Address=185.193.126.203/24
Gateway=185.193.126.1

DNS=95.215.19.53

[DHCP]
UseDNS=false
```

Comment: Thank you for this information! Additionally on my machine the config file is named `10-eth0.network` is there any significance for this number prefix ?