# Contents of /etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.network gets overwritten on reboot

Tags: linux-networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

I am using a VMware photon OS VM.

I want to configure a secondary IP address for my `eth0` interface.
And following the lead in : [How to configure interface aliases using Systemd-Networkd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1029004/how-to-configure-interface-aliases-using-systemd-networkd/1029157)

I added an additional `Address` and `Gateway` values as shown below:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=10.196.57.202/23
Gateway=10.196.57.253

Address=10.196.57.203/23
Gateway=10.196.57.253

DNS=10.202.22.165
LinkLocalAddressing=no
IPv6AcceptRA=no
```

202 is the primary and 203 is the secondary:

```
root@fgh-57-202 [ /etc/systemd/network ]# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b8:8f:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.196.57.202/23 brd 10.196.57.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.196.57.203/23 brd 10.196.57.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, after the reboot, the contents of the file : `/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.network`  Gets reset to:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=10.196.57.202/23
Gateway=10.196.57.253
DNS=10.202.22.165
LinkLocalAddressing=no
IPv6AcceptRA=no
```

I checked the `dhclient.conf` But cannot find anything suspicious:

```
root@fgh-57-202 [ /etc/systemd/network ]# cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
# Begin /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
#
# Basic dhclient.conf(5)

#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        ntp-servers;
require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;

# End /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

I am trying to get the secondary address to persist across reboots.